# Packer not finding some packages

Tags: archlinux, packer

`packer` seems to be missing some packages today. For instance, when I try to search for `texlive` it finds texlive properly. But when I instead search for `dropbox` or `spotify`, it doesn't return anything. Anybody else experiencing something similar?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: It isn't. But I thought this would be the best place to ask, didn't where else to direct this question!